# 'Another edit is awaiting approval for this post...' message not displaying in First Posts review queue

Tags: bug

Usually when you attempt to edit a question or an answer that already has an edit in the review queue you get following message:

[image]

I noticed while going through the *First Posts* review queue that when a question has already had an edit submitted for review, that dialog does not display. There is no indication of why the edit button is not displaying the edit feature.

It left myself confused for a minute until I opened the question in a new tab and tried editing it to realize that an edit was already waiting to be approved.

I can't confirm if the same thing is occurring in the *Late Answers* and *Triage* review queues.

EDIT: Realized that it is a bug and also a duplicate of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298797/editing-a-post-during-review-doesnt-show-an-edit-not-possible-message).

Comment: @AndrewT. thanks for that, should I delete this as it is a duplicate?

Comment: It's up to you, but IMHO your title is more descriptive and it can function as a good signpost to the duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewT. I agree with you too it is more descriptive.